# The most recent version of Spyder 5.0.0 will not run

Tags: spyder

My OS is Ubuntu and I have been using spyder for about a year with no problems. I usually install the updates when they are announced by updating anaconda and spyder with terminal commands. The most recent update spyder 5.0.0 will not run and I reinstalled the previous version. However, I still have spyder 5.0.0 and would like to know if I should wait for a later version and install that or try to remove it.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) For now the only solution os to downgrade to our 4.2.5 version. Hopefully this problem will be fixed in the next couple of days.

Comment: I was notified that they had fixed the problem and how to install te correction. I did so and it is working normally. The command is:   conda install spyder=5.0.0=*_1